# What's causing this orange light leak, vertical band, from an Olympus OM-1?

Tags: film, light-leaks, olympus-om1

My Olympus OM-1 typically doesn't have problems, but these two shots seems to show some kind of light leaks.

What I gathered with light leaks is that orange ones are probably from behind the film. The shutter is a horizontal cloth shutter, if that helps any.

The rest of the roll doesn't have any of these problems, which makes it even more interesting to diagnose...

Edit: The negatives
[image: Got the orange streak in many frames, but one of them is the worst]

[image: Orange / Red vertical light leaks] [image: A bit of blue leaks]

Comment: Is the damage at one end of the roll? Does the damage affect the edges of the film outside of the picture area?

Comment: @Stan I think those are the start of the roll. I should dig out the negatives.

Comment: It would be very informative to know if this recurs on a second roll. You may also try snapping a few photos so that you are in the middle of the roll and then letting the camera sit in a sunny spot (maybe even rotate it occasionally) to see if the discolorations appear in the middle of the roll.

Comment: Related: [Why am I getting vertical black bands across my negatives and how can I prevent this?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/70087/15871)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know this particular camera, but from the symptoms it looks very much like the back is not closing all the way.  I'm assuming the back is hinged at left, by the cartridge.  The leak is all along the right edge, which is where the largest gap would be if something isn't holding the back snug against the body.

It would have been helpful to see the whole width of the film, including the sprockets.  The sprockets are useful for diagnosing things like this because they should not be exposed at all when everything is working.

With film in the camera, close the back and look carefully at the right edge.  See if you can push on it a bit so that it closes more.  You shouldn't be able to do that, but I suspect you will be able to.  There is probably some sort of spring-loaded latch that isn't working anymore, but something else is still holding the back mostly shut.  Or, maybe you just didn't shut it quite right for this roll.

Comment: Given the review of the negatives, I'm leaning towards a bad door. Though teh hinge is on the right hand side.

Comment: The sprockets are exposed; you have a leaky back. Check / replace your light seals. Have look at this - http://aki-asahi.com/store/html/OM/light-seal/index.php (or have your camera serviced).

Comment: Or, if you're lazy like me you could fix it with this https://www.amazon.com/3M-Scotch-Photographic-Tape-roll/dp/B0001M6K3S

Comment: @JindraLacko I'll probably get it CLA'd and convert it to a 1.5v battery at the same time.

Comment: @Calyth I'd run another roll (test shots - nothing important) through it first. It could be possible the back just wasn't fully closed for whatever reason. A small scrap of paper or other detritus caught between the back and the main body is sometimes enough to compromise the seal.